# Alert for threshold in zeppelin data

Tags: analytics, apache-zeppelin

We are using zeppelin for metrics data visualization. Is there any possibilities in zeppelin to alert through mail for threshold (or) shall we integrate any code (scala,java or php) to raise mail alert for exceeding threshold.
We retrieve the data for visualization from mysql db

Answer (score 0):

Zeppelin is not about alerting.

It's better to use monitoring tools for alerting than write special code in Zeppelin.

Comment: We need alert based on the data visualized on zeppelin which exceeds the threshold